# How to get api format response from Django

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I followed "Writing regular Django views..." from the official documentation of `Django Rest framework` and got this kind of code:

```
#views.py file

#imports go here

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
"""
An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
"""
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

def items(request):
    output = [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"c":"3","d":"4"}]
    return JSONResponse(output)
```

And it works well. When a user goes to /items/ page, he or she sees a nicely looking json-formated data `[{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"c":"3","d":"4"}]`. But, how can I get (code?) api-formated data, or check if a user requested `?format=api` then render in api format manner and if not, then in json format. By api-formated data I mean this kind of [view](http://restframework.herokuapp.com/?format=api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the @api_view() decorator as described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view). And make sure you use the built in Response instead of JSONResponse.

Your view should then look something like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

...

@api_view()   
def items(request):
    output = [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"c":"3","d":"4"}]
    return Response(output)
```

In the case of getting the error

```
Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have model or queryset property
```

Remove DjangoModelPermissions from your rest framework permissions settings in you settings.py

Comment: Thank you, sir! However, in this case I get an error `Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have model or queryset property`. Can you, please, advise how to deal with this issue?

Comment: How's your DRF settings looking like? If you have DjangoModelPermissions as standard you might want to remove that, you can add it manually to any view should you need it later. A similiar issue is described here: https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/8

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have just deleted rest_framework.permissions from my settings file and it seems to work. So, the error message has gone away, but I still can not see how my output data can have api-formated view. It still has this json format, even if I go to items/?format=api. So, I guess I need some extra manipulations

Comment: Try changing the return statement to DRFS Response, eg: return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"}) instead of the JSONResponse class which now should be unnecessary